# Copy a layer and its settings to a different style in MapBox

Tags: mapbox

In MapBox, I have two distinct styles and need to use one heavily-customized group of layers which is currently in `Style A`, into `Style B`.

Doing it by hand (re-creating each layer in the group) could mean hours of work given the complexity of the settings, whereas having a copy/paste feature could mean achieving the same thing in seconds.

Is there a way to take a layer from one style and copy it (along with its settings) into another style, or do we have to re-create the layer — or group of layers — from scratch for each style we need it in?

Comment: Looking forward to see this option too, didn't find. That's crazy thing to handle it by hands.

Comment: this post hasn't been updated in while, has someone found a better way to do this? I'm stuck in the same point. I am trying to update a style in monthly bases, by changing the just one of the tileset id and is crazy if I have to do this manually. just for what ti looks to be pretty straight forward job

Answer (score 2):

I'm going through the same at the moment. What I have found to be quickest is to create a source style such as you have. I then download the style json isolate the layers I need in the style json and copy to the other style I need to use the same content.

3 things need to be handled, make sure you grab

1. Map ID of the source tile sets
2. Group details if any from the style meta data
3. All layers, this is made easier if you have clean layer name that are unique.

If you found a better way that would be great to hear.